# Varnish : VCL ~ with req value

Tags: syntax, varnish, vcl

I would like to avoid cache on same page depending of a cookie value (my user have profile with an URL like /firstname-lastname and can visit profile of other users).

In my cookies I store the "firstname-lastname" value, and try to make a test on it.
So I have made this :

```
set req.http.X-SLUG = regsub(req.http.cookie, ".*user_slug=([^;]+);.*", "\1");
if (req.url ~ "^/" + req.http.X-SLUG) {
```

And here the compilation error :

```
Expected ')' got '+' (program line 73), at ('conf.vcl' Line 50 Pos 28)
         if (req.url ~ "^/" + req.http.X-SLUG) {
 ---------------------------#-------------------
```

Do you knon how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In varnish, all regexes are compiled when the configurations are first loaded, and therefore must be static strings.

One way to work around this limitation is to use `regsub` call to extract the portion of the URL you are interested in, then test for equality:

```
set req.http.X-SLUG = regsub(req.http.cookie, ".*user_slug=([^;]+).*", "\1");
set req.http.X-TMP-URL = regsub(req.url, "^/(.*)$", "\1");
if (req.http.X-SLUG == req.http.X-TMP-URL) {
    ....
}
remove req.http.X-TMP-URL;
```

Note, in the above example I removed a `;` from the X-SLUG regex.  This allows the regex to work even when user_slug is the last cookie in the list.

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know that regexes were compiled at first load. Thanks